# Is it possible to use Kit3D in WPF? If so, how?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, 3d

I have a Silverlight application that uses Kit3D and I want to convert it to WPF.

How would I do that?

Should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try downloading the source code from its [Codeplex repository](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) and recompiling with WPF as the target.  No guarantees this will work without modifications, though, since WPF is not a complete superset of Silverlight.  But according to the author's description on his [web page](http://www.markdawson.org/Kit3D/), Kit3D is modeled after WPF's built-in [Media3D namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.aspx), so you could just use that directly rather than bother with a 3rd-party library.